# best way to dynamically populate .js properties from spring boot runtime application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

**tldr**

How to best "put" runtime application.properties values from a spring boot app in a javascript file

[Admittedly this is probably a stupid question for the experienced spring dev...so please share how to solve this problem "the spring way"]

**Context**

We have tiny app which a front-end developer put together and "threw over the wall"..It defines a properties file settings.js:

```
var SERVERROOT = 'http://solr:8983/solr/operations/select/';
```

referenced by html :

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src="js/settings.js"></script>
```

I would like to define the solr path in application.yml at runtime as follows:

```
app:    
   solr:
      path: 'http://solr:8983/solr/operations/select/'
```

**Question**

What is the best way to "populate" this settings.js value from application.properties (or equivalent, i.e. command line arguments, e.g.:

```
 -Dapp.solr.path=...
```

)

**Possible**

I thought about putting 'settings.js' as a thymeleaf template (settings.js.html) and having a spring controller populate the model from application.properties.

I didn't know if a more "native spring" method existed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a ResourceTransformer:

```
@Component
public class InjectSolrPathResourceTransformer implements ResourceTransformer {
    private final MySetting settings; // inject via constructor

    @Override
    public Resource transform(HttpServletRequest request, Resource resource, ResourceTransformerChain transformerChain) throws IOException {
if (request.getServletPath().equals("/js/settings.js")) {
            byte[] bytes = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
            String content = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            content = content.replace("var SERVERROOT = SERVERROOT_VALUE",
                                      "var SERVERROOT = '" + settings.getSolrPath() + "'");

            return new TransformedResource(resource, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } else {
            return resource;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that you change `settings.js` to be:

```
var SERVERROOT = SERVERROOT_VALUE
```

To use the `ResourceTransformer`, register it in your `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // inject this via constructor
    private final InjectSolrPathResourceTransformer resourceTransformer;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/js/")
                .addTransformer(resourceTransformer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added this ResourceTransformer class as above (with @Component annotation) , however spring does not call the .transform() method when the browsers hit this url --search/js/settings.js--nor any url.

Comment: @user331465 I updated how to register the transformer

Comment: Worked like a charm, except I had to apply the piece of @Haseb. 
One point to note is that the root of `ResourceLocation` is `/src/main/resources` and `ResourceHandler` is relative to `ResourceLocation`.
And the path in the call `getServletPath` is relative to `ResourceHandler`

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Wim above is correct but with new spring boot edition use the below code to register your transformer;

```
@Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // inject this via constructor
    private final InjectSolrPathResourceTransformer resourceTransformer;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/js/")
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addTransformer(resourceTransformer);
    }
}
```